# Replace the end of a File Name (SRC)

Tags: javascript, replace, filenames, src

i'm having a bit of a problem here. I found this script on the web, and changed it around a bit for my needs. 
This script shows a preview of the image following the mouse onmouseover.

Originally, there was only one way of doing this. But i have 2 different sections on my website in which i want to display images with different attributes (height, width).
I was able to do that, the problem is that on the second section, the src (file name) is a thumbnail of the actual picture i want to display, so when it dows, it just blows up a very small picture, which looks very bad. But hopefully, this will make things easier: all the thumbnails are named whaterver_small.jpg and the originals, whatever.jpg Now, if i could remove _small or _small.jpg and replace with .jpg from the end of that file, that would display the original picture for me, which would be great. This is how the funcion is called on html:

Original size, no need changing:

```
<a href=http://www.whatever.net/1.html');">
<img alt="Copper" border="1" height="64" src="http://www.whatever.net/whatever_small.jpg" width="85" onmouseover="showImage1(this.src,this,'Whatever')" /></a>
```

Show image2, the one i'm having problems with.

```
<a href=http://www.whatever.net/1.html');">
<img alt="Copper" border="1" height="64" src="http://www.whatever.net/whatever_small.jpg" width="85" onmouseover="showImage2(this.src,this,'Whatever')" /></a>
```

This is the script

```
    var floatWidth = 150;  // set the width of the floating image
    var floatHeight = 100;  // set its height
    var floatWidth2 = 320;  // set the width of the floating image
    var floatHeight2 = 240;  // set its height

    var midWindow = 0;
    var nContainer = "";
    var IE = false;

    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'){IE = true}

    function stayHome(m){        

            if (IE)
                    {
                    var currX = event.clientX;
                    var currY = event.clientY;
                    }
            else        {
                    var currX = m.pageX;
                    var currY = m.pageY;
                    }
            if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
                    {
                    var iL = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;        
                    var iV = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                    }
            else        {
                    var iL = document.body.scrollLeft;        
                    var iV = document.body.scrollTop;        
                    }
            if (currX > midWindow+80)
                    {
                    var msgWidth = nContainer.clientWidth;
                    if (IE){nContainer.style.left = (currX-msgWidth-10+iL)+'px'}
                    else {nContainer.style.left = (currX-msgWidth-10)+'px'}
                    }
            else        {
                    if (IE){nContainer.style.left = (currX+15+iL)+'px'}
                    else {nContainer.style.left = (currX+15)+'px'}
                    }
            if (IE){nContainer.style.top = (currY+iV-(floatHeight/2)+70)+'px'}
            else {nContainer.style.top = (currY-(floatHeight/2)+70)+'px'}
    }        

    function hideImage(){

            while (nContainer.lastChild)
                    {nContainer.removeChild(nContainer.lastChild)}
            document.getElementById('isFloat').style.display = 'none';
    }

    function showImage(isImg,currItem,currCaption){

            document.getElementById('isFloat').style.display = 'inline';
            nIMG  = document.createElement('img');
            nContainer.appendChild(nIMG);
            nIMG.setAttribute('src',isImg);
            nIMG.setAttribute('width',floatWidth);
            nIMG.setAttribute('height',floatHeight);
            nCaption = document.createElement('div');
            nCaption.style.textAlign = "center";
            nCaption.style.backgroundColor = '#EAE3C6';
            nCaption.style.padding = '5px';
            nCaption.style.color = '#000000';
            nCaption.style.fontFamily = 'Sans-serif';
            nCaption.style.fontSize = '10pt';
            nCaption.style.borderTop = "1px solid black";
            nContainer.appendChild(nCaption);
            nCaption.innerHTML = currCaption;
            currItem.onmouseout=hideImage;
    }

    function showImage2(isImg,currItem,currCaption){

            document.getElementById('isFloat').style.display = 'inline';
            nIMG  = document.createElement('img');
            nContainer.appendChild(nIMG);
            nIMG.setAttribute('src',isImg);
            nIMG.setAttribute('width',floatWidth2);
            nIMG.setAttribute('height',floatHeight2);
            nCaption = document.createElement('div');
            nCaption.style.textAlign = "center";
            nCaption.style.backgroundColor = '#EAE3C6';
            nCaption.style.padding = '5px';
            nCaption.style.color = '#000000';
            nCaption.style.fontFamily = 'Sans-serif';
            nCaption.style.fontSize = '10pt';
            nCaption.style.borderTop = "1px solid black";
            nContainer.appendChild(nCaption);
            nCaption.innerHTML = currCaption;
            currItem.onmouseout=hideImage;
    }


    function getMidWindow(){

            if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
                    {
                    midWindow = document.documentElement.clientWidth/2;
                    }
            else        {
                    midWindow = document.body.clientWidth/2;
                    }
    }

    function initFloatImg(){

            var nBody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            var nDiv = document.createElement('div');
            nDiv.id = "isFloat";
            nDiv.style.position = "absolute";
            nDiv.style.top = "0px";
            nDiv.style.left = "0px";
            nDiv.style.border = "1px solid black";
            nDiv.style.padding = "5px";
            nDiv.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff"
            nBody.appendChild(nDiv);
            nContainer = document.getElementById('isFloat');
            document.onmousemove = stayHome;
            hideImage();
            if (!IE){document.captureEvents(Event.mousemove)}
            getMidWindow();
    }

    onload=initFloatImg;
    onresize=getMidWindow;
```

Update:

Ok, so i updated the script in this page, and it works perfectly now.
I ran into another problem, when the picture that has the mouse over, is near the end of the page, the preview is cutoff. I'd like to be able to move the preview up, so there's no scroll bar.
Here's a live example of a functional one: http://www.soccer.com/Navigation.process?Ne=178&N=4294960224+346
Where the picture is never cutoff.

Comment: This script looking like it was lifted from a page in the 1990s. You're far better off looking at jQuery as part of the solution. You could do this in a few lines of code.

Comment: i'd love that, but i'm incredibly newbie when it comes to jquery

Comment: Time to take the leap. Writing separate code blocks for IE is madness.

Comment: Agreed. I got that code online, does the job, but you right, i should get into jquery. I'm trying. =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace following line in the `showImage2` function

```
nIMG.setAttribute('src',isImg);
```

with

```
nIMG.setAttribute('src',isImg.replace(/_small\./, '.'));
```

Comment: If you have a second, think you could take a look at that again? Thanks

Comment: If a question is solved you should accept an answer (no reputation needed, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/172024); reputation is only needed for upvotes). If you have an additional question you should create a new question and don't update the old one, because the new question will be sorted at the beginning of the queue, so many people can find it. An updated question only find people, which will see it randomly.

Comment: I have to go now, but I have an idea to solve your new issue. If I have a little time later I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know how to accept it, and i also didn't know if i should create a new question, so thanks for letting me know.
Thanks again @scessor

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all `_small` matches from all of your image sources, if I'm understanding what you want correctly:

```
$("img").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("/_small(?=\.)/", ""));
});
```

Comment: One suggestion: use `replace` the regex `/_small(?=\.)/` with a lookahead for a period at the end, so it only replaces when `_small` when it comes right before the extension.

Comment: No problem. If this answer was helpful to you, would you mind accepting and possibly upvoting it as well? (via the check-mark and up arrow directly to the left of my answer) Thanks! :)

Comment: as soon as i can, my "reputation" is too low still haha